# Get entire XML string from JSTree

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jstree

I have a JSTree populated by XML data. When I click on a button, I want to grab the entire XML of the tree. Right now I am using this:

```
var xmlString = $("#processTree").jstree("get_xml");
```

This works great when nothing has been touched in the tree, but if any nodes are selected when the button is clicked, it will only grab the XML from that node down to the bottom of it's children.

Is there a way to always grab the entire XML of the entire tree instead of just where a node is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by simply clearing any current selections in the process tree.

```
$.jstree._focused().deselect_all();
```